# Two select statement with case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two queries and I have a value if value is 1 then first query will execute if value is 2 then second. How can i achieve this, my query is

Query one if value is 1

```
SELECT  count (CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  )AS "matches" ,
              CAST( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' / 1' AS "match by"
              FrOM table a
              where ( SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS "matches"  )  >= 1
              group by  ( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
              )
```

Query 2 if value 2

```
 SELECT  count (CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    +  
                CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
                )AS "matches" ,
                CAST( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                +  CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/ 2'  AS "match by"
                FrOM table a
                where ( SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                 CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "NUM_OF_MATCHES"  )  >= 1
                group by  ( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+ 
                 CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
```

I have try it using case but it is not working

I want `if value = 1` then first query will run and `if value = 2` then second

although both queries doing same work but if value is 1 then col1 logic will take only col1 and if value is 2 then it will take col1 and col2 if value is 3 then it will take col1 col2 and col3 till 6 col

Comment: Try using `If @value =1 .....else if @value = 2 ...`. You can look it up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a simple `if else if` and execute both the queries.

```
   IF(@value=1)
    BEGIN
      SELECT  count (CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  )AS "matches" ,
                  CAST( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' / 1' AS "match by"
                  FrOM table a
                  where ( SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS "matches"  )  >= 1
                  group by  ( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
                  )
    END
    ELSE IF(@value=2)
    BEGIN 
       SELECT  count (CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    +  
                    CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  
                    )AS "matches" ,
                    CAST( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                    +  CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS VARCHAR(10)) + '/ 2'  AS "match by"
                    FrOM table a
                    where ( SELECT  CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
                     CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "NUM_OF_MATCHES"  )  >= 1
                    group by  ( CASE WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END+ 
                     CASE WHEN col2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
    END
```

Comment: i have a further questions . if want to order it in desc order it is not working  
More Over if i am using it in report it gives following error that it is aggregate function is there any better way to get result

Answer (score -1):

still are you using CASE Statement, why dont you try to use IIF Statement, IIF Statement is more efficient and fast compare to CASE Statement.

e.g.

```
select IIF(1=1, (your desired column1),(your desired column2)) as matches
```

you can also use nested IIF Statement in single query like CASE Statement..

```
select IIF(1=1, (IIF(2=2, (your desired column1),(your desired column2))),(your desired column3)) as matches.
```

Comment: IIF is not available in SQL 2008, it starts from SQL Server 2012.

Comment: sorry i was not aware about what you are using.